# Values from 2d array from 1d index array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, indexing

I have a two equal sized 2d arrays for which I what to find the maximum value in the first and the corresponding value in the other.

I can get the index for the maximum in the first array by using numpy.argmax(). This gives me an array of indexes for which I want to find the value in the second 2d array corresponding to that index.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[4,1,5,6],[6,8,1,2],[4,3,5,2],[5,6,2,8]])
b = np.array([[2,6,3,8],[3,5,8,3],[4,6,8,9],[6,2,4,7]])

index_max_a = np.argmax(a, axis=1)
print(index_max_a)
```

Which gives me:

```
array([3,1,2,3], dtype=int64)
```

Then my naive approach was to do:

```
b[:,index_max_a]
```

but this does not give the searched for list.

I can get the corresponding value to that index in b one by one as:

```
b[0,3]
b[1,1]
b[2,2]
b[3,3]
```

but can I do this in one swoop since I have the indexes in an array? I want to avoid using a for loop, since the arrays I am handling are quite large.

Ultimately a want to get a list which looks like (from this example):

```
array([8, 5, 8, 7])
```

It might be some syntax which I am missing.
Thank you.

Comment: `b[np.arange(index_max_a.size), index_max_a]`

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you very much.
On a more technical note: What is the difference between inputting a list as the first argument compared to the ":" which I tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using integer as index for multidimensional numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73745666/using-integer-as-index-for-multidimensional-numpy-array) (I am the author of the accepted answer.)

Comment: So in short: It is because the way the semicolon ":" indexes the rows is not the same way as calling each row manually, since there is some broadcasting performed in the semicolon operation?

Comment: If I then wanted to expand this to a 3d matrix instead of a 2d, how should I approach that? So my np.argmax(a, axis=2) is now a matrix. Can this scenario also be solved with a "oneliner"?

Comment: It can also be solved with one line, but it requires you to manually expand the axis to meet the broadcast conditions: `b[np.arange(b.shape[0])[:, None], np.arange(b.shape[1])[None], np.argmax(a, axis=2)]`